# How to save full list from pandas function into variable

Tags: python, pandas, list, function

I was having a problem when I created a function like this:

```
 def printlist(x):
        for column in x:
            global y
            print(list(x[column]))
```

I get a completely full list, as such:

> ['MATCH', 'MATCH', 'MATCH'] ['MATCH', 'MATCH', 'MATCH'] ['BUY', 'BUY',
>   'BUY']

However, when I try to save the list as a variable, it prints only the first list:

```
def printlist(x):
    for column in x:
        global y
        y = list(x[column])
        return y
```

> ['MATCH', 'MATCH', 'MATCH']

Would anyone know how I would be able to save the full list as a variable? Would greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: You create a new `y` for each column. Create `y` before the loop, then append to it. Also, your `return` will happen after the 1st iteration. Move that to outside the loop.

Comment: Would you be able to write out how the code would look? I playing around with it and couldn't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
def printlist(df):
    column_list = []
    for column in df:
         column_list.append(df[column])
    return column_list

list = printlist(df)
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it makes a lot of sense and works out. i was curious about how to manipulate the output though. Is there any way to save the output in a list format like [[match, match, match], [buy, buy, buy]]? where only the output from the columns is saved?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Because if you put in one dataframe, it will put all the column names of the one database in a single list. Where does buy, buy,buy come from?